# Override properties in application.yml with external file in integration test in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, properties-file

In `application.yml` I have a list of custom configuration for caching.

```yaml
caches:
  - name: cache1
    ttl: 30
  - name: cache2
    ttl: 60
```

I have an integration test and I want to *override* the values specified in `application.yaml` from external file.

I have several external cache configuration file for different tests, `test-caches-1.yml`, `test-caches-2.yml`, etc. The contents of file look simple

```
caches:
  - name: test-cache1
    ttl: 30
  - name: test-cache2
    ttl: 60
```

Here is my test

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = { "features.distributed-cache = true" },
        locations = {"classpath:/caches-configuratilon/test-caches.yml"})
public class CachingConfigurationTest {
    @Autowired
    CachesConfigurationProperties cachesConfigurationProperties;    

    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I remove `locations = {"classpath:/caches-configuratilon/test-caches.yml"}` attribute during test execution I see all caches from `application.yml`. If I put the contents of `test-caches.yml` to `application-test.yml` I see caches configured there.

But when I put those caches to  `test-caches.yml` there is nothing. Any ideas how can I override a values from `application.yml` with a values from external file `test-caches.yml`?

Comment: Why not use profiles, am I missing something?

Comment: It's only for several unit tests. Profiles will work but separate property files seems to be better solution for this case. Of course if it this kind of functionality is supported by Spring

Comment: I'd still have `application-test.yml` and put my properties regarding tests there.